# How to frequently update some particular field in database?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

This is my model to store bus details. Here I have kept a field named **bookedSeat** to store which seat is booked ( input a-z or A-Z ).
Every-time user book a seat a single character (inputted from user) should be added to **bookedSeat** field in database.

```
class busDetails(models.Model):
    busID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    arrival = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rent = models.IntegerField()
    distance = models.IntegerField()
    bookedSeat = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.arrival+' --> '+self.destination
```

I am getting stuck at how to frequently **update**(add into existing) that particular database field(bookedSeat)? (without adding any new row)
How do you solve this problem?
Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

Create an updateview for that Model and specify the fields that you would like to update. You can use a custom form, But trust me these generic views will save you a lot of time .

views.py :

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView


class updimagesUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = updimages
    fields = ['approval']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

Of all the attributes, you can mention the ones you need to be updated.
As shown in the last line above (template_name_suffix) , use the same naming suffix pattern for the template... [modelname_update_form.html] and display the form...

modelname_update_form.html :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load bootstrap_tags %}
{% block title %} Update {% endblock %}

{% block body%}
<div class="jumbotron">
    Are you sure you want to approve the Image ?
</div>
<br>

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|as_bootstrap  }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

make sure you get the corresponding element you want to update from the template :

```
<h3><a href="{% url 'images:update' pk=val.pk %}">update</a></h3>
```

clicking the above triggers the url. Add the urls ,

**urls.py:**

```
path('update/<int:pk>', views.updimagesUpdateView.as_view() , name = "update"),
```

PS: You can also update values from views using queries to select the desired object and then editing them like this ,

**in views.py :**

```
example = model.objects.filter(id=images.id).update(content=txt)
```

check  out the documentation for more info :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/